# C read file and print buffer

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C and I have been trying to read a file and print what I just read. I open the file and need to call another function to read and return the sentence that was just read.
My function will return 1 if everything went fine or 0 otherwise.
I have been trying to make it work for a while but I really dont get why I cant manage to give `line` its value. In the main, it always prints (null).

The structure of the project has to stay the same, and I absolutely have to use `open` and `read`. Not fopen, or anything else...
If someone can explain it to me that would be awesome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 50

int     read_buff_size(int const fd, char **line)
{
    char    buf[BUFF_SIZE];
    int     a;

    a = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
    buf[a] = '\0';
    *line = strdup(buf);
    return (1);
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char    *line;
    int     fd;

    if (ac != 2)
    {
        printf("error");
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        if((fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
        {
            printf("error");
            return (0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (read_buff_size(fd, &line))
                printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `fopen`and `fread` to read a file.

Comment: so you're _required_ to use low level `open/read` instead of `fopen/fread`?

Comment: @MPI_What - that's what `strdup` is supposed to do I think

Comment: yes i need to use low level functions. And I tried using malloc on line, it doesnt change anything, thats why I use strdup

Comment: My bad. Didn't read through thoroughly enough. Please ignore my comment!

Comment: Works fine for me when I compile and run your code, although you should be checking the return from `strdup()` and `read()`, and you should either read `BUFF_SIZE - 1` or make `buf` one character larger, amongst other things.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths have you tried changing the size of BUFF_SIZE ? if you put it at 5 for example it doesnt work anymore (on my computer at least)

Comment: @David: Yes, but if you change `char buf[BUFF_SIZE];` to `char buf[BUFF_SIZE + 1];` as I suggested, then I suspect you'll see that behavior change.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, you are right, wow that was stupid of me. Thank you very much, you are awesome.
Do i need to mark the question as "answered" ?

Comment: the `return` is an operator, not a function, so the parens are optional.   A return value of 0 indicates success.  suggest, when an error has occurred, to use: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  and when a system function, like `open()` fails, immediately call `perror()` which will ouput to stderr with the enclosed text and the appropriate system error message.

Comment: no one has yet posted an answer, these are only comments.  Perhaps Paul posts an answer, you can select it to indicate the accepted answer

Comment: what is the function: `read_buf_size()` supposed to return when the call to `read()` fails?

Comment: after the call to function: read(), check the returned value a. If < 0 and error occurred.  If >0 then that is number of bytes read.  if `a` is greater than or equal 0 but less than the number of bytes requested, then EOF encountered, so should sub function should not be called again.   However, there is no way for the main function to determine that event so will keep calling the sub function, long after the contents of the file are completely read/displayed.  similar conditions exist when an I/O error occurs.

Comment: the main() function has a massive memory leak.  The value returned from the sub function is a pointer to allocated memory (due to the strdup())  so the main() function, after printing the contents of the allocated memory, needs to pass that pointer to `free()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
char    buf[BUFF_SIZE];
int     a;

a = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
buf[a] = '\0';
```

if there are more characters than `BUFF_SIZE` available to be read, then you will fill your array entirely, and `buf[a]` will be past the end of your array. You should either increase the size of `buf` by one character:

```
char buf[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
```

or, more logically given your macro name, read one fewer characters:

```
a = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE - 1);
```

You should also check the returns from `strdup()` and `read()` for errors, as they can both fail.

Comment: Also, `read()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.  That makes a huge difference for 64-bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE); //UB if string is same or longer as BUFF_SIZE

u need +1 byte to store 0, so use BUFF_SIZE - 1 on reading or +1 on array allocation...also you should check all returned values and if something failed - return 0

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and take a look at:

https://github.com/mantovani/apue/blob/c47b4b1539d098c153edde8ff6400b8272acb709/mycat/mycat.c

(Archive form straight from the source: http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.tar.Z)

```
#define BUFFSIZE    8192

int main(void){
    int     n;
    char    buf[BUFFSIZE];

    while ( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
            err_sys("write error");

    if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");

    exit(0);
}
```

No need to use the heap (strdup). Just `write` your buffer to `STDOUT_FILENO` (=1)  for as long as `read` returns a value that's greater than 0. If you end with `read` returning `0`, the whole file has been read.

Comment: thks but i need to do it the other way because i have other operations to perform afterwards